# how to get next 50 items from a WellKnownFolderName in Exchange?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices

I'm developing an email client using EWS, in order to paging emails, I need to add paging function,　but how to get the next xx items from a WellKnownFolderName folder say inbox?
I use FindItemsResults findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(50)); get first 50 items. how to get the next 50 items? An example code will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there:

```
var items = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(50, 50));
```

The first parameter is the pagesize, the second parameter is the offset.